# How to use recursion on an array to calculate average?

Tags: c

I have a program that stores a variety of information about 10 universities as structures in an array. I have a function named 'inputData' that loads the information of the universities into the array by converting them to structures. I am trying to write a function that will recursively sum up the tuition of all the universities and then return the average. But I keep running into an error somewhere down the line.

This is the structure:

---

```
struct University
{
    char name[50];
    char city[20];
    char state[3];
    int rank;
    int tuition;
};
```

This is the function to convert info to a structure:

```
struct University inputData(char Name[50], char City[20], char State[3], int Rank, int Tuition){
    struct University uni;
    strcpy(uni.name, Name);
    strcpy(uni.city, City);
    strcpy(uni.state, State);
    uni.rank=Rank;
    uni.tuition=Tuition;
    return uni;
};
```

Then I created a structure array and added all the info:

```
struct University university[10];
university[0]= inputData("Princeton University", "Princeton", "NJ", 1, 45320);
university[1]= inputData("University of Virginia", "Charlottesville", "VA", 24, 52040);
university[2]= inputData("Boston College", "Chestnut Hill", "MA", 31, 51296);
university[3]= inputData("Georgia Institute of Technology", "Atlanta", "GA", 34, 32404);
university[4]= inputData("Lehigh University", "Bethlehem", "PA", 44, 48320);
university[5]= inputData("University of Chicago", "Chicago", "IL", 3, 52491);
university[6]= inputData("Duke University", "Durham", "NC", 8, 51265);
university[7]= inputData("University of Georgia", "Athens", "GA", 56, 29844);
university[8]= inputData("University of Denver", "Denver", "CO", 86, 46362);
university[9]= inputData("Loyola University Chicago", "Chicago", "IL", 99, 26270);
```

My function to calculate the average tuition is (I pass in the array and its length):

```
int recursionAvg(struct University* list, int length){
    if (length<=0){
    return 0;
}
    if(length!=0) return (recursionAvg(list, length -1) + list[length - 1].tuition)/10; 
};
```

I call it and print the result by doing:

```
average = recursionAvg(university, 10);
printf("the average is: %d", average);
```

I'm supposed to get 43561 as the answer but I keep getting 3126. I realize that the part of the problem is because I keep dividing by 10 in every recursive call, but how would I do this only once within the function itself?

The code runs but I get the wrong result.

Comment: No warnings from your compiler? `recursionAvg` doesn't have a return value for all code paths.

Comment: I had a return path, I commented it out. Ill put it in the edit.

Comment: And are you sure dividing by `10` for every recursive call is correct?

Comment: I thought something was off about that. How would I go about  doing it at the end, only once?

Comment: A struct with fixed-length `char` fields is asking for trouble. Consider `char*`.

Comment: pseudocode for a non-recursive sln: `for (int i=0, double result=0; i< university.length(); i++) { result += university[i].tuition / (i+1) }`

Comment: thank you but i need a recursive solution for this problem

Comment: This is way too much code to experiment with. Tip: Try on a trivial structure like an arbitrary sized set of `int` values. Do you want to do a *tail recursive* version or a version that splits by half each time?

Comment: Tip: Be aware that `int / int = int` and **rounding will occur**. You probably need a `double` to compute your average.

Comment: I'm fine with an int result for the purposes of this program. Thank you

Comment: How about computing the sum recursively and dividing the result by the number of elements only after the recursion is complete?

Comment: I could do that, but I really want to see if I could do it within the function itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a recursive implementation using [incremental averaging](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1836447/143176).  I would strongly recommend that this be done with doubles to avoid the int/int rounding issues:

```c
double avg_tuition(struct University* list, int n) {
    if (length <= 0) {
        return 0.0;
    }
    double running_avg = avg_tuition(list, n - 1);
    return running_avg + (list[n - 1].tuition - running_avg) / n;
}
```

You can then cast or round the result to int.

If you insist on using integer arithmetic:

```c
int avg_tuition(struct University* list, int n) {
    if (length <= 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    int running_avg = avg_tuition(list, n - 1);
    return running_avg + (list[n - 1].tuition - running_avg) / n;
}
```

but this gives imprecise results due to the cumulative effects of integer truncation.  The good news is that this will not be subject to overflow when the original data fits into your `int` type, since it works with differences between the running average and each new observation rather than accumulating a large sum (which is where potential overflow would occur).

Answer (score 1):

Heyo!

If we follow through your recursive calls, you'll find that `recursionAvg` instantly calls itself with (length - 1). This is because the base case is only triggered when length == 0, and in the recursive case, your function is called straight away. This causes the function to be called 10 times in a row, and only then will the magic happen. Once we get to length == 1, the function is called with length = 0, and it returns 0. In short, the function then computes: `(recursionAvg(list, length -1) + list[length - 1].tuition)/10;`, which is `(0 + list[0].tuition)/10`. The function call with length == 1 then returns and progressing starts for length == 2. The return value of the function with length == 1 is used. However, this has already been divided by 10! As such, the function call with length == 2 will return `((0 + uni1/10) + uni2)/10`. Notice that this nesting of division will continue all the way back up the recursion chain and eventually compute the monstrous:

```
((((((((((((((((((0 + 45320/10) + 52040) / 10) + 51296) / 10) + 32404) / 10) + 48320) / 10) + 52491) / 10) + 51265) / 10) + 29844) / 10) + 46362) / 10) + 26270) / 10
```

If you print this, you'll sure enough get 3126!
Notice that in order to compute the average, you shouldn't divide each intermediate result by 10, you should first sum all of the values, and then divide the end result by the number of universities. I would recommend doing this with an iterative approach, since it's more intuitive. However, if you'd like to use a recursive approach, note that the laws of division and addition tell us that: `(a + b + c + d ...) / n == a/n + b/n + c/n + d/n ...`. Therefore, we can compute each term separately in the function, and sum the result recursively. All you have to do to make this happen is to not divide the whole result by 10, but only item[length - 1]:

```
    if (length <= 0)
        return 0;
    else
        return recursionAvg(list, length-1) + list[length - 1].tuition/10;
```

However, consider the fact that this way you divide 10 times, rather than once. Do note that due to integer division the result will not exactly match!

Answer (score 0):

As [@tadman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87189/tadman) pointed out

> Be aware that int / int = int and rounding will occur

For example in the code that you provided this sum will occur:

```
suma = 45320+52040+51296+32404+48320+52491+51265+29844+46362+26270
```

wich result it is

```
suma = 435612
```

But the `int` type in C is between this range *-32768 and 32767*, so
given that `435612 > 32767` the value of this sum I think it's been truncated to
`32767`.